# Convert Multiple Lists with each list is nested with list of differing length into multiple data frames

Tags: r

I am reading PDF documents and reading the tables in each of the PDF document

```
library(tabulizer)
filenames <- list.files(path="C:/Gear_Box",pattern="*.pdf")
```

Create list of names without the ".pdf" part

```
names <-substr(filenames,1,9)

for(i in names){
filepath <- file.path("C:/Gear_Box",paste(i,".pdf",sep=""))
assign(i, extract_tables(filepath), envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

Multiple lists are created here

[image: Thus created list is as follows]

Now, I'm capturing all list that are available in environment

```
all <- mget(objects[sapply(objects, exists)])
```

Here nested list created as follows

[image: Here nested list created as follows]

Now, I am trying to convert them into multiple data frames

```
for (i in 1:length(all)){
for(j in names){
assign(paste0(j,"_", i), as.data.frame(j[[i]]))
}
}
```

Getting error as follows:

```
Error in j[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Please help and correct my code

```
dput(all)

 list(V057_1205 = list(structure(c("Plant Name:", "Component Name:", 
 "Test Depot", "1205", "Area:", "Machine Name:", "B92", "V057"
 ), 
 .Dim = c(2L, 4L)), structure(c("Lab Comment:", "Level of wear and 
 contamination appear satisfactory.", 
 "There are no indications from the oil analysis data of abnormal 
  wear or oil", 
  "condition. All parameters are within acceptable limits.", 
   "Continue sampling at scheduled interval.", 
   "Overall Status Satisfactory", "Sample Current", "No", "Ref Oil 
    Reference", 
    "Oil", "Sample Date 29/06/2022", "Oil Hours", "Unit Hours", 
    "Sample # 18857", 
    "Alarm Radar:", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
     ""), .Dim = c(14L, 2L)), structure(c("Sample", "", "Ref Oil", 
     "", "Sample Date", "Oil Hours", "Unit Hours", "Sample #", "Lab 
     #", 
     "Analyst", "Wear", "Aluminium - ppm", "Antimony - ppm", "Cadmium 
     - ppm", 
     "Chromium - ppm", "Copper - ppm", "Iron - ppm", "Lead - ppm", 
     "Nickel - ppm", "Tin - ppm", "Titanium - ppm", "Vanadium - ppm", 
     "Manganese - ppm", "PQ - idx", "Chemistry", "Barium - ppm", 
     "Boron - ppm", 
      "Calcium - ppm", "Magnesium - ppm", "Molybdenum - ppm", 
      "Phosphorus - ppm", 
       "Potassium - ppm", "Zinc - ppm", "Viscosity 40 - cSt", "Sulfur 
       - ppm", 
       "Contamination", "Aluminium - ppm", "Silicon - ppm", "Sodium - 
        ppm", 
        "Water Content - %", "Visual", "Oil Hours - hrs", "Unit Hours 
        - hrs", 
        "Visual - hrs", "", "No", "Reference", "Oil", "29/06/2022", 
         "", 
         "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
         "", 
         "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
         "", 
         "", "", "", "", "", "", "Current", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
         "18857", 
         "3", "Oil", "", "9", "< 1", "< 1", "1", "10", "80", "< 1", " 
         < 1", 
         "2", "< 1", "< 1", "1", "39", "", "1", "2", "4", "2", "1", 
          "2120", 
          "1", "11", "165.1", "17590", "", "9", "3", "2", "< 0.02", 
           "", 
           "", "", ""), .Dim = c(44L, 3L)), structure(c("Key", 
           "Satisfactory", 
           "Early Caution", "Caution", "Warning", "Action", "Page 1 
            of 1"
            ), .Dim = c(1L, 7L))), V057_1470 = 
           list(structure(c("Plant Name:", 
           "Component Name:", "Test Depot", "1470", "Area:", "Machine 
            Name:", 
            "B92", "V057"), .Dim = c(2L, 4L)), structure(c("Lab 
             Comment:", 
             "Level of wear and contamination appear satisfactory.", 
             "There are no indications from the oil analysis data of 
             abnormal wear or oil", 
             "condition. All parameters are within acceptable 
             limits.", "Continue sampling at scheduled interval.", 
             "Overall Status Satisfactory", "Sample Current", "No", 
              "Ref Oil Reference", 
              "Oil", "Sample Date 29/06/2022", "Oil Hours", "Unit 
               Hours", "Sample # 18857", 
               "Alarm Radar:", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
               "", "", "", 
              ""), .Dim = c(14L, 2L)), structure(c("Sample", "", "Ref 
              Oil", 
              "", "Sample Date", "Oil Hours", "Unit Hours", "Sample 
              #", "Lab #", 
             "Analyst", "Wear", "Aluminium - ppm", "Antimony - ppm", 
             "Cadmium - ppm", 
             "Chromium - ppm", "Copper - ppm", "Iron - ppm", "Lead - 
              ppm", 
              "Nickel - ppm", "Tin - ppm", "Titanium - ppm", 
              "Vanadium - ppm", 
              "Manganese - ppm", "PQ - idx", "Chemistry", "Barium - 
              ppm", "Boron - ppm", 
              "Calcium - ppm", "Magnesium - ppm", "Molybdenum - ppm", 
             "Phosphorus - ppm", 
              "Potassium - ppm", "Zinc - ppm", "Viscosity 40 - cSt", 
              "Sulfur - ppm", 
              "Contamination", "Aluminium - ppm", "Silicon - ppm", 
              "Sodium - ppm", 
              "Water Content - %", "Visual", "Oil Hours - hrs", "Unit 
               Hours - hrs", 
               "Visual - hrs", "", "No", "Reference", "Oil", 
               "29/06/2022", "", 
               "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
               "", "", "", 
               "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
               "", "", "", 
               "", "", "", "", "", "", "Current", "", "", "", "", "", 
               "", "18857", 
               "4", "Oil", "", "5", "< 1", "< 1", "< 1", "4", "28", " 
               < 1", "< 1", 
               "2", "< 1", "< 1", "< 1", "5", "", "1", "3", "8", "5", 
               "1", "2198", 
              "< 1", "10", "158.6", "16390", "", "5", "1", "1", "< 
               0.02", "", 
               "", "", ""), .Dim = c(44L, 3L)), structure(c("Key", 
               "Satisfactory", 
               "Early Caution", "Caution", "Warning", "Action", "Page 
               1 of 1"
               ), .Dim = c(1L, 7L))), V057_5005 = 
               list(structure(c("Plant Name:", 
               "Component Name:", "Test Depot", "5005", "Area:", 
               "Machine Name:", 
               "B92", "V057"), .Dim = c(2L, 4L)), structure(c("Lab 
               Comment:", 
               "Level of wear and contamination appear 
                satisfactory.", "There are no indications from the 
                oil analysis data of abnormal wear or oil", 
                "condition. All parameters are within acceptable 
                limits.", "Continue sampling at scheduled interval.", 
                "Overall Status Satisfactory", "Sample Current 
                Historical", "Ref Oil No Reference Oil", 
               "Sample Date 29/06/2022 11/09/2021", "Oil Hours", 
                "Unit Hours", 
                "Sample # 18857 16764", "Lab # 1 1", "Alarm Radar:", 
                "", "", 
                "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), .Dim = 
                c(13L, 2L)), 
                structure(c("Sample Current", "Ref Oil No Reference 
                Oil", 
                "Sample Date 29/06/2022", "Oil Hours", "Unit Hours", 
                "Sample # 18857", 
                "Lab # 1", "Analyst Oil", "Wear", "Aluminium - ppm 
                5", "Antimony - ppm < 1", 
                "Cadmium - ppm < 1", "Chromium - ppm 1", "Copper - 
                ppm 3", 
                "Iron - ppm 48", "Lead - ppm 1", "Nickel - ppm 1", 
                "Tin - ppm 2", 
                "Titanium - ppm 1", "Vanadium - ppm < 1", "Manganese 
                 - ppm 6", 
                 "PQ - idx 9", "Chemistry", "Barium - ppm 4", "Boron 
                 - ppm 1", 
                 "Calcium - ppm 31", "Magnesium - ppm 2", "Molybdenum 
                  - ppm 1", 
                 "Phosphorus - ppm 2063", "Potassium - ppm 42", "Zinc 
                - ppm 15", 
               "Viscosity 40 - cSt 141.3", "Sulfur - ppm 15570", 
               "Contamination", 
               "Aluminium - ppm 5", "Silicon - ppm 3", "Sodium - ppm 
                23", 
               "Water Content - % < 0.02", "Visual", "Oil Hours - 
                hrs", 
               "Unit Hours - hrs", "Visual - hrs", "Historical", "", 
               "11/09/2021", 
                "", "", "16764", "", "Oil", "", "", "< 1", "< 1", "", 
                 "", 
                "50", "", "", "", "< 1", "< 1", "", "10", "", "", "", 
                "38", 
                "", "", "2168", "48", "19", "139.9", "16630", "", "", 
                 "", 
                 "24", "< 0.02", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
                 "", "1", 
                 "", "", "6", "", "", "1", "4", "", "1", "1", "1", 
                 "", "", 
                 "7", "", "", "4", "3", "", "2", "2", "", "", "", "", 
                  "", 
                  "", "6", "3", "", "", "", "", "", ""), .Dim = 
                  c(42L, 3L)), 
                  structure(c("Key", "Satisfactory", "Early Caution", 
                  "Caution", 
                   "Warning", "Action", "Page 1 of 1"), .Dim = c(1L, 
                    7L))), 
                    V057_5034 = list(structure(c("Plant Name:", 
                    "Component Name:", 
                    "Test Depot", "5034", "Area:", "Machine Name:", 
                    "B92", 
                    "V057"), .Dim = c(2L, 4L)), structure(c("Lab 
                     Comment:", "Note level of copper.", 
                     "There is evidence of elements consistent with 
                      bearing wear or material from", 
                      "other bronze surfaces.", "Resample to monitor 
                      wear levels recommended.", 
                      "Overall Status Caution", "Sample Current 
                       Historical", "Ref Oil No Reference Oil", 
                       "Sample Date 29/06/2022 30/09/2021 
                       11/09/2021", "Oil Hours", 
                      "Unit Hours", "Sample # 18857 16902 16764", 
                      "Lab # 2 1 2", 
                      "Alarm Radar:", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
                      "", "", "", 
                      ""), .Dim = c(13L, 2L)), structure(c("Sample", 
                      "Ref Oil", 
                      "Sample Date", "Oil Hours", "Unit Hours", 
                      "Sample #", "Lab #", 
                      "Analyst", "", "Aluminium - ppm", "Antimony - 
                      ppm", "Cadmium - ppm", 
                      "Chromium - ppm", "Copper - ppm", "Iron - ppm", 
                      "Lead - ppm", 
                      "Nickel - ppm", "Tin - ppm", "Titanium - ppm", 
                      "Vanadium - ppm", 
                      "Manganese - ppm", "PQ - idx", "", "Barium - 
                       ppm", "Boron - ppm", 
                       "Calcium - ppm", "Magnesium - ppm", 
                       "Molybdenum - ppm", "Phosphorus - ppm", 
                       "Potassium - ppm", "Zinc - ppm", "Viscosity 40 
                       - cSt", "Sulfur - ppm", 
                       "", "Aluminium - ppm", "Silicon - ppm", 
                      "Sodium - ppm", "Water Content - %", 
                     "", "Oil Hours - hrs", "Unit Hours - hrs", 
                     "Visual - hrs", 
                    "Current Historical", "No Reference Oil", 
                    "29/06/2022 30/09/2021", 
                    "", "", "18857 16902", "2 1", "Oil Oil", "Wear", 
                   "20 15", 
                   "< 1 < 1", "< 1 < 1", "1 1", "67 59", "124 85", "< 
                    1 1", 
                   "< 1 < 1", "2 < 1", "< 1 < 1", "< 1 < 1", "1 1", 
                   "4 5", "Chemistry", 
                   "< 1 < 1", "4 4", "5 2", "18 13", "< 1 < 1", "2021 
                    1543", 
                    "3 1", "26 16", "174.7 179.3", "17000 12910", 
                    "Contamination", 
                    "20 15", "1 1", "4 3", "< 0.02 < 0.02", "Visual", 
                     "", "", 
                     "", "", "", "11/09/2021", "", "", "16764", "2", 
                    "Oil", "", 
                     "18", "< 1", "< 1", "1", "65", "122", "< 1", 
                     "1", "< 1", 
                     "< 1", "< 1", "1", "5", "", "1", "7", "9", "17", 
                     "< 1", "2159", 
                     "2", "32", "183.9", "18260", "", "18", "1", "3", 
                     "< 0.02", 
                     "", "", "", ""), .Dim = c(42L, 3L)), 
                    structure(c("Key", "Satisfactory", 
                    "Early Caution", "Caution", "Warning", "Action", 
                    "Page 1 of 1"
                     ), .Dim = c(1L, 7L))))
```

Comment: Can you please provide example data (as text) and your desired output?

Comment: What if you replace ` as.data.frame(j[[i]])` with ` as.data.frame(get(sym(j))[[i]])`

Comment: if you want to convert each item into each element of the list as a data frame (each sublist of the main list will have 4 dataframes): `all <- lapply(all, \(x) lapply(x, as.data.frame))`

Comment: I want to convert each sub list into data frame; here all has 4 lists inside it; V057_1205 is one among them. V057_1205 has lists inside it. I need to convert each of the V057_1205 into a data frame out side. That is not within the list. Create data frame object outside the list environment

Comment: It is difficult to help when we dont get example data to work with. Could you share the `all` object by appending the output of `dput(all)`?

Comment: I have placed dput(all) data in the original post above